# Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and is committed to Git

Tags: spring-mvc, heroku, procfile

This is the folder structure of my project:

```
- Root-folder
    .git
    projecname
        Procfile
        pom.xml
```

This is the `Procfile` configure:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT  --proxy-base-url https://projectname.herokuapp.com target/*.war
```

I used Profile to deploy project on heroku from Local:

```
cd projectname
git push heroku master
```

but I got the erorr when deploying:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz
remote:        Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and is committed to Git.
remote: 
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

as I understand, the reason is: the root folder that `Heroku` use to run `maven` build is the same folder containing `.git` is: `Root-folder` and the `pom.xml` file is in `Root-folder/projectname` folder.

So my question is how can I set the `build path` to heroku know where is containing the `pom.xml` file?

Thank you in advance.

---

**SOLVED**

I have read this article: https://medium.com/@timanovsky/heroku-buildpack-to-support-deployment-from-subdirectory-e743c2c838dd

then setting PROJECT_PATH by command:
`heroku config:set PROJECT_PATH=projectname`

Comment: Solved by: 
https://medium.com/@timanovsky/heroku-buildpack-to-support-deployment-from-subdirectory-e743c2c838dd

then setting PROJECT_PATH by command:
`heroku config:set PROJECT_PATH=projectname`